# Huawei React Native Map Kit Markers not rendered with bottom tabs

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services

I added the code like [shirley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13329100/shirley) said [mateovlz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10163126/mateovlz) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759188/blank-space-mapview-react-native-hms) and when I navigate to another tab and back to map tab the markers are not rendered.

This problem is not reproduced when we navigate inside the Map component through a StackNavigator but it happened when we use TabNavigator.

my BottomTabNavigator code is declared like this:

```js
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TabScreens = (navigation) => {

    const getTabBarVisible = (route) => {
        if (route.state && route.state.index > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    return (
        <TabNavigator.Navigator
            initialRouteName={"Tab1"}
            tabBarOptions={{
                allowFontScaling: false,
            }}
            tabBar={(props) => <CustomTabBar {...props} />}>
            <TabNavigator.Screen
                name={"Tab1"} // This is the name that shows as label
                component={HomeTab}
                screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false, swipeEnabled: false, lazy: false, animationEnabled: false }}
                options={({ route }) => ({
                    tabBarVisible: getTabBarVisible(route),
                    headerShown: false
                })}
            />
            <TabNavigator.Screen
                name={"Tab2"} // This is the name that shows as label
                component={MerchantTab}
                screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false, swipeEnabled: false, lazy: false, animationEnabled: false }}
                options={({ route }) => ({
                    tabBarVisible: getTabBarVisible(route),
                    headerShown: false
                })}
            />
            <TabNavigator.Screen
                name={"Tab3"} // This is the name that shows as label
                component={HealthTab}
                screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false, swipeEnabled: false, lazy: false, animationEnabled: false }}
                options={({ route }) => ({
                    tabBarVisible: getTabBarVisible(route),
                    headerShown: false
                })}
            />
            <TabNavigator.Screen
                name={"Tab4"} // This is the name that shows as label
                component={Map}
                screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false, swipeEnabled: false, lazy: false, animationEnabled: false }}
                options={({ route }) => ({
                    tabBarVisible: getTabBarVisible(route),
                    headerShown: false
                })}
            />
            <TabNavigator.Screen
                name={"Tab5"} // This is the name that shows as label
                component={MoreTab}
                screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false, swipeEnabled: false, lazy: false, animationEnabled: false }}
                options={({ route }) => ({
                    tabBarVisible: getTabBarVisible(route),
                    headerShown: false
                })}
            />
        </TabNavigator.Navigator>
    )
}
```

and Map.js

```js
const Map = ({ navigation }) => {
    const merchants = useSelector(state => state.content.content);
    const [initialRegion, setInitialRegion] = React.useState({ latitude: 37.983810, longitude: 23.727539, latitudeDelta: 8, longitudeDelta: 8 });
    const locale = translation[useSelector(state => state.content.locale)];

    return (
        <HMSMap
            // ref={mapRef}
            style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0
            }}
            initialRegion={initialRegion}
            showsUserLocation={true}

        >
            {
                merchants.map(marker => {
                    return (
                        <HMSMarker
                            coordinate={marker.location}
                        />
                    )

                })

            }
        </HMSMap>
    )
}
```

- react: 16.13.1
- "react-native": "0.62.2"
- @react-navigation/bottom-tabs: 5.4.2
- @react-navigation/native: 5.3.0
- @react-navigation/stack: 5.3.3,
- react-native-hms-maps 4.0.2

Comment: It's a RN Map Kit bug, and we are working on it. I will get back to you if the issue is fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have addressed this issue and working on fixing it.

Thanks